# Can't figure out how inotifywait excluding works, can somebody explain?

Tags: bash, posix, inotifywait

I have the following peace of code in bash

```
inotifywait -r -m -e modify -e moved_to -e moved_from -e move -e move_self -e create -e delete -e delete_self $list_of_folders |
    while read path action file; do
        message=$myip%0A$action%0A$path$file
        message
    done
```

I don't know how can I exclude from watch files named "logs.txt"  and ".git" folders, can anyone explain how  excluding works in inotifywait?

p.s. logs.txt and .git folders, may be in any location, I don't know exactly where

Comment: `inotifywait` has an `--exclude` option.  Does it do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on John1024's comment, I believe you need to use `--exclude 'logs\.txt|\.git'` in your `inotifywait` command like this:

```bash
inotifywait --exclude 'logs\.txt|\.git' -r -m -e modify -e moved_to -e moved_from -e move -e move_self -e create -e delete -e delete_self $list_of_folders | # ...
```

This option takes a regular expression that is used to ignore events whose filename matches it. In this case, the regular expression `logs\.txt|\.git` means any filename equal to `logs.txt` or (`|`) `.git`. The backslashes are required to escape the dots because they have a special meaning inside regular expressions.

This exclusion seems to work well for any location of the `logs.txt` file or `.git` directory. And it even excludes events from descendants of the `.git` directory.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i looking for.